# INSERT INTO NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Preciso criar um INSERT onde seja verificado se o valor já existe. Olhei alguns posto, mas não estou conseguindo executar.

```
INSERT INTO `pagina_extra` (`ID_PExtra`, `ordem_paginas`, `id_menu`, `url_seo`, `url`, `nome`, `titulo`, `conteudo`, `exibir`, `interno`)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'NULL', '3', '1', 'downloads', 'pag_downloads.php', 'Downloads', '', '', 'N', 'N') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT url_seo FROM pagina_extra WHERE url_seo = 'downloads'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Erro que aparece quando vou testar diretamente no Phpmyadmin:

> Duplicate column name 'Downloads'

Mas não existe nenhum valor para acusar duplicado. O que está errado?

Comment: a query não esta vendo as palavras com `case sensitive` então quando voce diz `'downloads'` e `'Downloads'` fica sendo a mesma coisa.

Comment: E qual a solução?

Comment: não sei em que ponto do desenvolvimento você esta mas o ideal era deixar os nomes das colunas diferentes, até porque fica muito estranho e talvez gere algum transtorno futuro tendo 2 colunas com o mesmo nome.

Comment: resolveu seu problema ?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa dar um alias para cada coluna do seu select, pois o erro diz que as colunas possuem nomes iguais.

O resultado ficará assim:

```
INSERT INTO `pagina_extra` (`ID_PExtra`, `ordem_paginas`, `id_menu`, `url_seo`, `url`, `nome`, `titulo`, `conteudo`, `exibir`, `interno`)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'NULL' AS ID_PExtra,
                '3' AS ordem_paginas,
                '1' AS id_menu,
                'downloads' AS url_seo,
                'pag_downloads.php' AS url,
                'Downloads' AS nome,
                '' AS titulo,
                '' AS conteudo,
                'N' AS exibir,
                'N' AS interno) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT url_seo FROM pagina_extra WHERE url_seo = 'downloads'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Teste da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(50)
SET @Var = (SELECT url_seo FROM pagina_extra WHERE url_seo = 'downloads')
IF @Var <> 'downloads'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO pagina_extra (ID_PExtra, ordem_paginas, id_menu, url_seo, url, nome, titulo, conteudo, exibir, interno)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'NULL', '3', '1', 'downloads', 'pag_downloads.php', 'Downloads', '', '', 'N', 'N') AS tmp
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [LOWER](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_function_upper_lower.php) para torna o valor do seu campo idêntico.

```
INSERT INTO `pagina_extra` (`ID_PExtra`, `ordem_paginas`, `id_menu`, `url_seo`, `url`, `nome`, `titulo`, `conteudo`, `exibir`, `interno`)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'NULL', '3', '1', 'downloads', 'pag_downloads.php', 'Downloads', '', '', 'N', 'N') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT url_seo FROM pagina_extra WHERE LOWER(url_seo) = LOWER('downloads')
) LIMIT 1;
```